Breaking a trade embargo
Say country "A" has an embargo against purchasing items from country "B" . John Doe is a private businessman who is interested in doing business with country "B" anyway. He ships a boat load of merchandise from country "B" to country "A". Other than refusing to allow him to dock,  not allowing his merchandise to be taken off the ship and it's possible confiscation what other consequence, if any, does he risk by breaking the embargo as a private citizen of another country?

An embargo is a restriction on purchasing goods in a country from a second country.  It's like a boycott by a nation.  It doesn't prevent anyone else from buying goods from the embargoed country.  John is free to pick up cargo from Country B, but if he tried to bring that product to Country A he would be subject to  confiscation, fines, prison, etc., according to the embargo in Country A.  He is free to sell Country B's products to Countries C-Z.  John's nationality is immaterial.
A blockade is an act of war that prevents any country from doing business with a country under threat of military force.  A blockade would sink or confiscate John's ship going to or from Country B.
Note that countries (like the US) may create things like trade restrictions that other nations do not technically have to follow but which the restricting country enforces by other political or economic means.  This would prevent John from doing any business with Country B under threat of whatever enforcement the restricting country has put in place, from fines and arrest to being bombed.  Note that these restrictions could be written to disallow nationals of the restricting country from doing trade with a nation under penalty of legal action.

John’s nationality is definitely not immaterial. Most sanctions prohibit any citizen from doing business with the sanctioned nation. If John is a citizen of A, he is immediately a criminal as soon as he starts doing business with B, even if the goods will never enter A.

@DaleM, that isn't an embargo, it is sanctions.

Same thing, different name

Depends on how the embargo is written, but there is a high likelihood that country A is going to punish citizens of A, residents of A, and legal entities registered in A if they trade with B.
It might go so far that entities in A are forbidden from trading with companies in C which do trade with B (secondary sanctions). The limits on this are legally the domestic laws in country A, and politically/economically the ability of country A to make entities in other countries go along.

One example was when the US wanted to force a Chinese bank to stop dealing with North Korea.
Another example was when the US left the JCPOA with Iran. Powerful countries opposed the action by then-President Trump.

A detailed answer to this question has to name countries A and B, because national law is key here.

An embargo is essentially a local law forbidding certain actions and defining certain consequences for violation.
For example, the US embargo on Cuba is enacted through a succession of several different laws over the decades expanding the list of restricted activities and their scope.
In some cases (including the US-Cuban, Egyptian-Israeli, or the Israeli-Gazan cases), what one side is considering to be a trade restriction or a security measure, the other side may consider to be a blockade, an act of war.
Embargoes may also be coordinated and enforced by multiple countries (e.g.: South Africa, Iran, North Korea), in which case the violations may be handled differently in each of the embargoing countries depending on the local laws and politics. The US, for example, has been known to sell weapons to Iran despite the official embargo.
The restrictions may apply on country A's entities only (e.g.: the initial US Cuban embargoes), or any entities involved with country A (e.g.: US Cuban embargoes now, US FATCA), or any entities shipping to B (e.g.: the Israeli/Egyptian weapons embargo over Gaza).
The risk thus depends on the underlying legal authority and reasoning, and ability and willingness of the embargoing party to enforce. It can be anywhere from silently looking the other way to violently sinking the transport and drowning everyone on it.
